# Boostrap is not displaying the background color of my form

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using bootstrap for the design of my form, but it's not showing the back-ground color of the form, like it's in the examples.

All the fonts colors sizes & designs of the bootstrap are applied, but the background of my form is missing.

I also copy and pasted all the code from the example to see if it will show the form background, but even then it didn't show the background-color of the bootstrap theme.

I have included `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` in my html file.

This is the theme that I am using: https://bootswatch.com/flatly/

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Users</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form class="form-horizontal col-lg-7" style="border: 1px solid red;" action="/index.php">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputUsername" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Enter Username">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-3">
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset </button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: put your won style.css file at bottom of all links

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Users</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <!-- my style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing code before the fiedset tag:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Users</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <form class="form-horizontal col-lg-7" style="border: 1px solid red;" action="/index.php">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-bs-6">
            <div class="well bs-component">
              <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputUsername" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Enter Username">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-3">
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset </button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```